# Is Fast Track Security in Heathrow included with business class tickets?

Tags: lhr, united-airlines, turkish-airlines

I'll be flying into and out of Heathrow in November via business class (United Polaris business class and Turkish Airlines Business Class).

In reading about [Fast Track Security](https://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/terminal-facilities-and-services/fast-track/airline-eligibility) it sounds like my ticket should include Fast Track Security already and that I shouldn't need to pay the £12.50 or whatever that it normally costs? Is that correct?

Comment: Based on the list of participating airlines, this seems correct (for security at departures or during a connection at least — the rules seem to be more complex for arrivals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast-track for departures is included:

> Fast Track departures is available to first and business class passengers in addition to top tier members of airline frequent flier programmes.

([Source](https://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/terminal-facilities-and-services/fast-track/airline-eligibility))

For arrivals it is a bit more complicated:

> Fast Track Arrivals in Terminals 2, 3 and 4 is available to invited Non-EU Premium Passengers. Please be aware that eligibility criteria will vary between participating airlines. Passengers are advised to check with their airline representative upon arrival at Heathrow or alternatively please refer to your airline’s website.

(Same Source)

You may need to check with your airline or on arrival.

Comment: Available and included are not necessarily the same thing lol. Like snacks are often available in economy class but they're not included - you have to pay extra for them.